# Unable to import external module in Angular2 with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I am trying to import [marker-animate-unobtrusive](https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive) library into my angular2 project. And since it already has a type definition, I have tried like this:

```
npm install marker-animate-unobtrusive  --save
npm install @types/marker-animate-unobtrusive --save
typings install dt~google.maps --global --save
typings install dt~marker-animate-unobtrusive --global --save
```

After successful installation, I am trying to import one of the modules like this:

`import * as SlidingMarker from 'marker-animate-unobtrusive';`

But at that moment, I am getting this error:

```
File '/Users/.../node_modules/@types/marker-animate-unobtrusive/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

But I checked the [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/marker-animate-unobtrusive/index.d.ts) and found that module is already declared.

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

```
Hash: 561cad2f71e8d09ae7cf
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
Time: 9538ms
           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  main.bundle.js    3.55 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
styles.bundle.js    10.2 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
       inline.js    5.37 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
        main.map    3.63 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
      styles.map    14.1 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
      inline.map    5.55 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
      index.html  478 bytes          [emitted]  

ERROR in [default] /Users/.../src/app/trip/map-content-component/map-content-component.component.ts:6:26 
File '/Users/.../node_modules/@types/marker-animate-unobtrusive/index.d.ts' is not a module.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  2.81 kB       0       
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Comment: When did you get this error?

Comment: @RomanC, during compile time.

Comment: Post a stacktrace.

Comment: @RomanC, There isn't a stack trace that I could find. Though I have edited my question to put exact error. I am getting the very same error in browser console.